# Как предсказать положение спутника?

Tags: python

Как, зная координаты ЦУП (центра управления полетами) и TLE-координаты ИСЗ (искусственного спутника земли), на python предсказать оптимальное время и длительность связи с ИСЗ для обмена данными? Вроде бы нужна модель SGP4, но толкового найти ничего не смог.

**Координаты ЦУП**

```
Широта: 55°45′07″ с.ш.

Долгота: 37°36′56″ в.д.
```

**TLE МКС**

```
"GALILEO-PFM (GSAT0101)", 

"1 37846U 11060A   12293.53312491  .00000049  00000-0  00000-0 0  1435", 

"2 37846  54.7963 119.5777 0000994 319.0618  40.9779  1.70474628  6204"
```

Comment: Вопрос явно не по тегу "Python" . Ибо предсказывает не Python, а соответствующий алгоритм предсказания. Вот напишите алгоритм, а потом реализовывайте его хоть на Python, хоть на Lisp, хоть на счетах. Будут вопросы по реализации именно на Python - приходите, задавайте.

Comment: @passant, вероятно автора интересует какая-то питоновская библиотека